# hierarcical select not apply parent restriction

Tags: taxonomy-terms

i want to add a  "category" field in my custom content type.category type is "terme refrence" with ***hierarcical select wideget*** . in settings of it i restrict it with set parrent term for it
[image]

but in my form not resriction happend !!!

[image]

but in ***$form['field_category']['und']['#config']*** have this 
[image]

what is the problem and what is the correct way to restrict HS to pick up only sub term of optional term?(i have a vocabulary with a lot of term,i don't want split it to some vocaublary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventually i found  this is a bug in hierarcical select module, and the 
[patch in here](http://drupal.org/node/263365#comment-6107218)

i hope this  be useful.